# UINavigationController setNavigationBarHidden: with a completion block on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiviewanimation

I am hiding the Navigation Bar of a UINavigationController by sending the message:

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

I'd like to know if there is any change to get a callback or completion block when the animation completes. Something like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{

}completion:^(BOOL finished){

}];
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for my, hope this help.

God luck!

```
 [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
                       options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                    animations:^{
                        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden];                            
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        NSLog(@"hide animation finished");
                    }];
```